# Avoiding getting text wrapped around the code tag when text is with certain tag

Tags: php, regex

I am using a Wordpress plugin that puts the code tag around text that is in backticks for highlighting purposes on my blog. Now the original function is this:

```
function mdc_the_content( $content ) {

    $content = preg_replace( '/`(.*?)`/', '<code>$1</code>', $content );
    return $content;

} // mdc_the_content
add_filter( 'the_content', 'mdc_the_content' );
```

When I am using js highlighter plugin (code highlighter) then it places the code tag around the code that is in backticks. I want to avoid that. Would the function below work? Only put the code tag around tags when the backticks are not wrapped in `<pre class="EnlighterJSRAW" data-enlighter-language="r">$1</pre>`. Would the if statement below work? Sometimes there might be multiple objects wrapped around backticks within the highlighter. Thank you.

```
function mdc_the_content( $content ) {

    if(!preg_match('/`(.*?)`/', '<pre class="EnlighterJSRAW" data-enlighter-language="r">$1</pre>', $content)) {
        $content = preg_replace( '/`(.*?)`/', '<code>$1</code>', $content );
    }

    return $content;

} // mdc_the_content
add_filter( 'the_content', 'mdc_the_content' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
$content = preg_replace( '~<pre\s+class="EnlighterJSRAW"\s+data-enlighter-language="r">.*?</pre>(*SKIP)(*F)|`(.*?)`~s', '<code>$1</code>', $content );
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0XeFYv/1).

The `<pre\s+class="EnlighterJSRAW"\s+data-enlighter-language="r">.*?</pre>(*SKIP)(*F)|` part matches the `pre` tag with two specific attributes allowing any amount of whitespace and all contents in it, and the `` `(.*?)` `` will match in all other contexts.